# How do I change the default padding that Material-UI seems to apply to all its components

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

The AppBar component for instance doesn't cover the whole area by default, I looked through the documentation and on google but couldn't find a solution for it.

I also tried changing the spacing in createMuiTheme for my Layout component which included the AppBar and {props.children} at the end. That didn't seem to do anything.

Tl;dr : I want the app bar and all the other components to cover the whole screen, use the whole screen as a flex without padding which material-ui seems to be adding to it by default.

[image: Wish it could cover the whole width of page instead of leaving those margins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the margin given by the `body` of html document. You have to apply following styles:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you're using JSS solution that is given by `material-ui` then add following in your root styles object:

```js
{
  // ...

  '@global': {

    // ... global styles here

    body: {
      margin: 0,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved it but I still need to know, why was there a default margin, was it applied by material ui after all ? I can share the code with you if you need to know that to answer it.

Comment: No its not applied by material-ui nor react. It's default behavior of html pages. Maybe it's given by the browsers.

Comment: That's strange because when I create just an index.html page with no styling there is no margin or padding.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>Hello</body>
</html>` This is giving me margin.

Comment: I just tried and it is in fact happening, must have been a false memory, my bad.